# Multiple Functions on a Single Event with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to call two functions upon a single click event?

There will be multiple elements requiring this script, so the script must act only upon the element being clicked — not all the elements at once.

Let me know if I need to provide more details. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        func1();
        func2();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery will handle that for you quite nicely, see example:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text()+' clicked');
})
.click(function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'#ff0000'});
});
```

```html
<div>Button 1</div>
<div>Button 2</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pcASq/

Comment: Chaining 2 click events together is wrong. aSeptik has it right.

Comment: I fail to see how that is wrong.  I demonstrated "how to call two functions" in jQuery.  Sure you could combine them (the way that aSeptik did) and use named functions however this is a perfectly valid alternate demonstration of multiple bindings on a single element.

Comment: I meant its the wrong way to go about it. It does work but not effeciant

Comment: The question had nothing to do with how to bind but rather how to call.  Sure, chaining in that manner is silly (for that matter why even have two functions?)  Rather to demonstrate that jQuery "events" only impact the clicked element, not all elements originally bound.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid and nicely demonstrates multiple bindings on the same event.

Comment: It's not "the wrong way to go about it". jQuery supports this functionality because they designed it to work this way. It's perfect OK to do what @JasonBenson suggested.