# Jquery - Two variables in one .click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have variables that have multiple functions in them. I then want to call these variables in a .click event. One works fine, but I want to have two, or even more. How can I do this? Below is the code I would expect to work.

```
var hideServices = function() {
            jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "0"});
};

var showMilitaryKit = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
};

var showProperty = function() {
            jQuery(".property-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
};

    jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(hideServices, showMilitaryKit);

    jQuery(".property-hover").click(hideServices, showProperty);
```

I'm convinced I haven't combined my variables in the .click event on the last line properly, but I can't find any documentation on what I want to achieve. Does anyone have a tweak that would work for me?

Comment: can you not just club the 2 functions into 1 ?

Comment: No. I'll amend my question so you can see why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Functions on a Single Event with JQuery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951388/multiple-functions-on-a-single-event-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I agree. It's the exact same question. Mine just goes into more detail with the question, but the answer is effectively the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the two calls in an anonymous function:

```
jQuery('.military-kit-hover').click(function() {
    hideServices();
    showMilitaryKit();
});
```

If you need to preserve the event object or `this`, do this:

```
jQuery('.military-kit-hover').click(function(e) {
    hideServices.call(this, e);
    showMilitaryKit.call(this, e);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(function() {
    hideServices();
    showMilitaryKit();
});
```

More in `JQuery.click()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/).